# All Tumblr URLs pointing to my Wordpress website Broke with SSL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

Last week, I transitioned my website to SSL by using a plugin called Really Simple SSL.

It all went smoothly, however, I noticed that ever since activating the plugin and going SSL, my site lost 1/3 of its traffic, which was coming from external Tumblr links on my Tumblr blog that pointed at the http version of my website.

When I click on those Tumblr links now, I get a blank page that says:

> *{"error":"Redirect failed"}*

Here's an example of such Tumblr link would be.
*(Not including my actual website's domain here cause it is an adult site)*.

*http://t.umblr.com/redirect?z=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&t=YmY1YWYwZTI0MmU3YmQzNzEyYmJjN2MzYjY0NjJlZDk5ZTFlN2RmMCxPTGo3TU5iOQ%3D%3D*

It occured to me that those hundreds of old links all point to the http version of my site, but for some reason, they're not getting correctly redirected to https as they should be doing.

The http to https redirect definitely works every other time, but for some reason, with old Tumblr URLs it doesn't.

**Any clues on what could be the cause of this?**
I already tried to tweak the settings of my site, like, for example:

Adding this to my wp.config.php file:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); 
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) 
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Editing .htaccess manually with these lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But alas, neither seems to have worked.
Is there a way I could fix this?

Again, **the HTTP to HTTPS redirects work for literally everything,** except those Tumblr URLs, which are, very unfortunately, a huge source of traffic for my site.